# Konvajs - how to take a screenshot without transparency

Tags: konvajs, todataurl

Im just trying to let my user take a screenshot using the toDataUrl() function.

but, without a background rectangle, all pixel are transparent , and appear black .

so the solution is to dynamicly add a rectangle, generate the image, destroy the rectangle

```
           saveImage(){

               const stage=this.$parent.$refs.stage.getStage()
               var stageRect =  new Konva.Rect({
                   x:0,
                   y:0,
                   width: stage.attrs.width,
                   height: stage.attrs.height,
                   fill: 'green',
               })
              console.log(stage)
               const backg=new Konva.Layer();
               backg.add(stageRect)
               stage.add(backg)
               backg.setZIndex(0)
               const dataURL = stage.toDataURL({ pixelRatio: 1, mimeType:"image/png" });
               backg.destroy();
               this.downloadURI(dataURL, 'stage.png');

           },
```

it works (rectangle is created before all other layer) but... i can't get the size of the stage, i mean, the viewport because the user can zoom/dezoom the stage .... 
any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a scale to calculate background properties:

```
var stageRect =  new Konva.Rect({({
  x: -stage.x()/ stage.scaleX(),
  y: -stage.y()/ stage.scaleY(),
  width: stage.width() / stage.scaleX(),
  height: stage.height() / stage.scaleY(),
  fill: 'green',
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/lehasitaje/2/edit?html,js,output